# HTML5 Video with controls without timeline

Tags: html, css, reactjs, html5-video

I'm trying to disable the video timeline in a video
I used this

```
<video width={600} controls>
         <source src={'/myvideo.mp4'} type="video/mp4" />
</video>
```

And wrote this css for it

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
     display: none;
}
```

which is working perfectly on desktop and android but it is still visible on Ios (safari or chrome)

Comment: Hi! did you try  ::-webkit-media-controls , ::-webkit-media-controls-panel

Answer (score 1):

Disabling the timeline in iOS browsers like Safari can be a bit tricky due to the limited support for styling certain parts of the default media controls. However, you can try using the following approach to hide the timeline on iOS:

Try adding '!important':

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
     display: none !important;
}
```

Also if it doesn't works, you might need to consider using a custom video player library or building a custom video player with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript, which would give you full control over the appearance and behavior.

Try this: https://plyr.io/

[npm library - plyr](https://www.npmjs.com/package/plyr)